# Why and how are t and b options of figure treated differently?

Tags: floats, positioning

I try not use `[h]` much for figures (nor for floats in general). On the contrary I try to use `[b]` and `[t]`, but I've often noticed that the two behave differently. I'm pretty sure it is intended and that things must be done that way, but I'm curious about it.

**Example**

One figure is at the top thanks to `[t]`. The section it belongs to begins just after the figure. Then there is the obvious page break at some point in the section.

This means that the float and that portion of text can be in one page, since they are there.

Changing the option to `[b]` I'd expect that the float and the text after it in the same page be switched (the figure under the same text it had after it, not one line more, not one line less), using the same amount of space between line, between possible formulae, between those elements and the figure, ...

No, the figure goes to the end of the chapter (taking with it all the following figures).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The underlying code treats top and bottom floats in a more or less symmetric manner but the default values of the parameters make it easier to set top floats.

`latex.ltx` has

```
\setcounter{topnumber}{2}
\newcommand\topfraction{.7}

\setcounter{bottomnumber}{1}
\newcommand\bottomfraction{.3}
```

so for example a float that is half a page in height may be placed at the top but not the bottom, unless you change these parameters, or use `[!b]` where the `!` (just) means to ignore the parameters.

Note that not including `p` makes it far more likely that the float goes to the end of the document, so `[tp]` is usually a better option than `[t]`  for example.

Comment: Wow, it's so much time I don't write extensively in LaTeX that I forgot I could use `!`! Anyway thank you for the concise and complete answer.

Comment: As a side question: do you have any idea about the reason of these and other asymmetries? Do you think it was just a matter of someone's taste?

Comment: @EnricoMariaDeAngelis Leslie Lamport's taste yes, but as far as I can see it is a taste shared by many others as most journal classes seem to use very similar values. But note that (in the absence of `[b]` etc) latex always tries top floats first so bottom floats a bottom float won't be tried unless the top float area is already full, so allowing 70% of the page to go into the bottom area may not make a good default